# How to automatically hyperlink to folders from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 500 folders with a specific string of names 
e.g., `Aseem-tb-rd-001`, `Taj-tb-rd-006`, etc..

Each folder has two sub-folders, exactly named `In` and `Out`.

Now I have an Excel file with sheets named `In` and `Out` in it,
Both these sheets have the respective string of names. I need Excel to automatically fetch the folder and add the hyperlink.

e.g., if cell `H3` in sheet `In` has the name `Taj-tb-rd-006`, I want the hyperlink to link to the folder `Taj-tb-rd-006\In`
and if cell `H8` in sheet `Out` has the name `Taj-tb-rd-006`, I want the hyperlink to link to the folder `Taj-tb-rd-006\Out`.

Can this be done by any means?

Comment: Welcome to SU! Yes, you can write a VBA macro that uses the content of the cells to make a hyperlink.

Comment: There is a formula called hyperlink.  A combo of this formula and the name manager is how I would approach this task.  IS this enough or is there more that you need?

Comment: If you could help me with how to do it, I would be more than gratefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a formula. I would start with:

=HYPERLINK(H3&"\out")

**Edit**
Sorry, misread the question. The other half of the answer is that you need some VBA code like this, modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380381/4836664) on SO:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant, i As Integer
    file = Dir("D:\My Folder\", vbDirectory)
    While (file <> "")
       i = i + 1
       ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = file
       file = Dir
   Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you elaborate it please. I'm a complete idiot in this .

Comment: I've added code that will pull the directory names from the given folder into a column in your active sheet. Run it for one of your worksheets, then copy it into the other. Use the formula to get the hyperlinks, one ending in \in and one ending in \out.